# Is there a way to modify alpha in a texture without affecting the RGB values?

Tags: three.js, glsl

I need to sample the RGBA values of a texture, and I'm using the `alpha` channel to store custom data, not really to as opacity. The problem is that as `alpha` approaches 0, my RGB values also get multiplied towards 0, but I need them to remain independent.

My first render pass gets rendered into a `WebGLRenderTarget`, and this is how I'm storing data in GLSL into the `alpha` channel:

```
gl_FragColor.rgb = mainColor;
gl_FragColor.a = depthData;
```

the result shows Alpha fading to white as expected:
[image]

My second render pass gets rendered to the canvas, so I read the RGB values from from the first texture in GLSL, with alpha as 1:

```
gl_FragColor.rgb = texture2D(tColor, vUv).rgb;
gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
```

The result should be the regular RGB values of the spheres, but it seems that the RGB values fade to black when Alpha approaches 0.

[image]

Is there a way to use the alpha channel as data storage without affecting the RGB values? I've tried setting the target texture's [`premultiplyAlpha = false`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.premultiplyAlpha) as follows, but it doesn't change anything:

```
var target = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(
    window.innerWidth,
    window.innerHeight, {
        format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
        type: THREE.UnsignedByteType
});
target.texture.premultiplyAlpha = false;
```

#### Update:

I was building a [working demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/n0d42xpr/), and I was unable to reproduce the bug. It looks like I'm going to have to rip apart my entire project until I get to the bottom of this...

Comment: Have you, also, tried creating the [WebGLRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer)  context with `premultipliedAlpha: false`?

Comment: @ScieCode I did try that, both true and false yielded the same results. Sorry, I should've clarified that.

Comment: Post more code, ideally in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: 1. what is your blending function? 2. do you have buffer bits allocated to alpha channel? 3. `gl_FragColor.rgb = mainColor; gl_FragColor.a = depthData;` would worry me as after first assignment of color the shader could stop due optimizations I would set both RGB and a in single line `gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(tColor, vUv).rgb,1.0);` 4. do you have the same order of rendering in both passes (you know blending is order dependent)?

Comment: If the sphere's material is using the default blending, it is possible the RGB channel information is getting blended with the background information and that's what's causing the loss of color info. Setting `material.blending` as `THREE.NoBlending` might fix this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everybody! I was trying to recreate the bug [in a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/n0d42xpr/) but for some strange reason, it's working fine there. I'm going to have to keep digging on my project to get to the bottom of this...